# How can I know if an item in a TableView got truncated (got ellipsis)?

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

I'm using a TableView. The String data that it needs to display has variable length. How can I know if the String data was too long (and hence got ellipses)?

My guess is to use a custom TableCell (calling setCellFactory()), and in the updateItem() I should query the pixel-width of the data, but I don't know how.

```
        column.setCellFactory(column ->
            new TableCell<Transaction, String>() {
                @Override
                protected void updateItem(final String item, final boolean empty) {
                    super.updateItem(item, empty);
                    setText(item);


                    if (/*measuredWidth > getWidth()*/) {
                        setTooltip(new Tooltip(item));
                    }
                }
            }
    );
```

Any ideas on this?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I know for a label you do this: `label.setMinWidth(Region.USE_PREF_SIZE);`  Maybe it's similar...

Comment: you can query the cells prefWidth and compare it to the column width (guessing, didn't try ;)

Comment: Did you figure this one out? I'd like to do this too...

Comment: Not yet. I added tooltip for all items regardless of what their width was. For now.

Comment: Ok figured it out...

Comment: Improved on answer to fix bug where tooltips would start drifting to other cells.

Answer (score 0):

```
column.setCellFactory(col -> new TableCell<Object, String>()
    {
        @Override
        protected void updateItem(final String item, final boolean empty)
        {
            super.updateItem(item, empty);
            setText(item);
            TableColumn tableCol = (TableColumn) col;

            if (item != null && tableCol.getWidth() < new Text(item + "  ").getLayoutBounds().getWidth())
            {
                tooltipProperty().bind(Bindings.when(Bindings.or(emptyProperty(), itemProperty().isNull())).then((Tooltip) null).otherwise(new Tooltip(item)));
            } else
            {
                tooltipProperty().bind(Bindings.when(Bindings.or(emptyProperty(), itemProperty().isNull())).then((Tooltip) null).otherwise((Tooltip) null));
            }

        }
    });
```